# abline() is not working with weighted.hist()

Tags: r, r-environment

So I used the `plotrix` library to plot a histogram using some weights , the histogram shows up as expected but when I tried a plot the mean as a vertical line it won't show up at all 
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
library("plotrix")
library("zoom")


vals = seq.int(from = 52.5 , to = 97.5 , by = 5)
weights <- c(18.01,18.26,16.42,14.07,11.67,9.19,6.46,3.85,1.71,0.34)/100

mean <- sum(vals*weights)
wh <- weighted.hist(x = vals , w = weights , freq = FALSE)
abline(v = mean)
```

the `abline()` seems to work only with the normal `hist()` function

I am sorry if the question sounds stupid , I am R newbie however I did my research and could not find any helpful info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To give a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is helpful to provide some data via `dput()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a sample of your data. Your calculation of the weighted mean is only correct if your weights sum to 1. If they do not, you should use `weighted.mean(vals, weights)` or `sum(vals * weights/sum(weights))`. The following example is slightly modified from the one on the `weighted.hist` manual page (`help(weighted.hist)`):

```
vals <- sample(1:10, 300, TRUE)
weights <- (101:400)/100
weighted.hist(vals, weights, breaks=1:10, main="Test weighted histogram")
(mean <- weighted.mean(vals, weights))
# [1] 5.246374
```

The histogram starts at 1, but this is 0 on the x-axis coordinates so we need to subtract 1 to get the line in the right place:

```
abline(v=mean-1, col="red")
```

[image: Histogram]

Using your data we need to identify the first boundary to adjust the mean so it plots in the correct location"

```
wh$breaks[1]
# [1] 52.5
abline(v=mean - wh$breaks[1], col="red")
```

[image: New Histogram]

Comment: my weights sum up to 0.9998 but it's no big deal since it's so close to 1 , how would that affect printing the vertical line?, btw why did you create 299 weights instead of 300? (400-101 = 299) since you had your sample size = 300

Comment: and as i mentioned above i am sure the problem has nothing do with the data set itself but rather weighted.hist() since i tried hist() with a test data set and i can plot the vertical line just fine

Comment: `length(101:400)` is 300 just like 1:10 is 10 values, not 9. Since you provided no data, it is impossible to say why you did not get a line.  Since the axis coordinates start at 0, but your first histogram bar probably started at a number greater than that, it may have plotted outside the figure.

Comment: fine then i will provide the dataset

Comment: ohh  i get it now , one last thing , does R always have the x-axis start at 0?

Comment: and of course thx a lot for your help much appreciated

Comment: No. The programmer sets the coordinates for the plot window. Generally they do match the range of the data, e.g. the `hist` and `plot` functions. You can always retrieve them with `par("usr")`. For  your data that returns -1.8000000 46.8000000  0.0000000  0.3990498 so the vertical axis is positioned at -1.8 on the horizontal axis and the first bar starts at 0.